# Copy data from worksheets with partial name relation

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from every sheet in my workbook that has "ANALYSIS E 000002" and then "ANALYSIS E 000002" in its name, up to "ANALYSIS E 000012". Some have a copy number after this string, i.e. "ANALYSIS E 000002 (3)".

So I started by doing a vba code that will take every sheet in the workbook and add their content in a combined one. It works perfectly but now I need to adapt it to select only the string I specify. I will need to do it for different names.

Started with this code :

```
Sub Combine_ea()
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next

Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1:A2").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1:A2")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A3").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(2, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A99999").End(xlUp)(2)
Next

End Sub
```

The approach I think would be the best is to make a For loop to reach every string that finishes by my Iterator and then do my algorithm. I am not sure how to do adapt my code at this point. Would need help from you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "like".

For example,

```
If Sheets(1).name like "Analisis*"
then 
--Your code here
End If
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as I see, you don´t need to paste all information in a sheet, you can use an input box for asking the user the name of the string he/she wants to look for, and then look for the sheets called that way, and then look for the range that has the word you are looking for. Here´s an example:

```
Sub example()

Dim res As String
Dim no As Integer

res = InputBox("Write the name you want to look for")
no = Len(res)  'gets the amount of characters in the string


For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count

If Left(Worksheets(i).Name, no) = res Then 'reads the name of the worksheet form left 
to right
                                       'gets the number of characters in the variable 
                                        no and compares the substring with the string 
                                        res


      'if you are here it means the worksheets is called as you out in your input box
      'from here you can do what you want, use the same structure to look inside the 
       cells

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I did something like this but without the part with the inputbox as there is no user in my situation. I made an IF statement for each string I want to compare and then looped in it so I can copy all data from worksheets to my main one.